# Active Reports (Page Reports) Multiple Tables

Tags: vb.net, activereports

I have seen this solved many times in Section Reports, but I am looking for something similar to Subreports for page reports. My report needs to present multiple tables. I have attempted to solve this by creating a new page for each table, but only page one is being generated. Do I need to link the pages to the viewer in the code? Is this the proper way to use the page tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under ideal situations, one need not link each page to the viewer in the code. Once the pages are created, the same are displayed in the viewer without any issues.

As per my understanding of the issue, you wish to bind your report to multiple datasources and then show the data in various [tables](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/Table.html)/[dataregion](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageReportModel.DataRegion.html)/[subreports](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/SubreportReportItem.html). If this is the case, then the suggestion would be make use of [CPL](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/ColumnarReportsCPL.html) PageReport wherein you can bind it to multiple datasources.

You mat refer to [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/SubreportinCPLReport.html) walkthrough illustrates how to create a report using a subreport.

Regards,
Mohita

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that there are different types of PageReports. I see now that CPL has the sub report functionality. Now my only issues is that all of my sub reports will not fit on one page.

Comment: @DavidPrice :
Are you looking for a scenario wherein all the subreports appear on one page only? If yes, then this isn't possible as it is dependent on the page size and the data.If the data is more than the pagesize, the subreport will overflow on following pages.

And if you wish to display each subreport on different/new page then you may add this subreport in a Container control and make use of [PageBreakAtEnd/PageBreakAtStart](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/AddPageBreaks.html) property of the Container control.This way a pagebreak  can be set before or after.